# I need help solving this riddle! It's driving me crazy!

Tags: riddle

Both a noun and a verb, but issued in a tiny blurb. 
An airplane today, trash tomorrow, all of these require a bit of power.
Delivered via server, mail or store; throw it away, or use it some more.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? Please mark as ✔ Accepted if so.  If not, you may want to add a comment to people's answers to let them know if they're off-base, or if they're just missing a small thing or what.

Answer (score 36):

Hobbit78, huh.
The answer is "a ring!"

<sup>oh. wait. wrong riddle.  confound it ...</sup>

I think it is:

> **FLYER**

because

> It can be a noun or a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flyer#Verb);
>  flyers are often used to provide short advertisements, like a blurb,
>  it's an airplane (a flyer), the paper may be trash tomorrow,
>    and it takes a (tiny) effort to distribute flyers, to fly a paper airplane or to throw away trash.
>  You can get flyers via email, mail, or in a store;
>  you can recycle the paper or discard it.

Comment: Nice one. I was thinking "receipt" but I think you've nailed it.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is

> Paper

Both a noun and a verb

> Paper is a noun (obviously), but you can also use it to paper something (which is a verb).

, but issued in a tiny blurb.

> I feel like this is just here for the rhyme.

An airplane today

> Paper airplanes

, trash tomorrow

> Trashed paper

, all of these require a bit of power.

> Not clear on this line.

Delivered via server

> Your check at a restaurant is printed on paper and delivered by the server.

, mail

> Letters.

or store

> You can buy paper at a store.

; throw it away

> You can throw away paper.

, or use it some more.

> Or you can reuse paper.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is:

> page

Both a noun and a verb , but issued in a tiny blurb.

> You can page someone (with a pager) and when issued in that way it is only a tiny blurb of a sentence or two

An airplane today, trash tomorrow, all of these require a bit of power.

> Paper plane, paper trash, not sure about a bit of power

Delivered via server, mail or store;

> A web page is delivered via server, a page of a letter is delivered via mail, and a page of a book is delivered by store

throw it away, or use it some more.

> A page can be reused

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is:

> package

Both a noun and a verb,

> You can package something, or deliver a package.

but issued in a tiny blurb.

> Package is a single, relatively short word

An airplane today, trash tomorrow, all of these require a bit of power.

> Not quite sure on this one, although it could refer to means of transporting packages (airplanes) and opening packages (turning them into trash), both of which use energy

Delivered via server, mail or store;

> Web servers send data in packages, packages can be delivered by mail, or you can buy packages (of things) in stores

throw it away, or use it some more.

> Packaging can be thrown out or reused